# Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 12

Tags: php, regex

My WordPress website has a Warning on a grid article saying:

> preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 12 in wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/classes/shortcodes/vc-basic-grid.php on line 177

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    die( '-1' );
}

require_once vc_path_dir( 'SHORTCODES_DIR', 'paginator/class-vc-pageable.php' );
require_once vc_path_dir( 'SHORTCODES_DIR', 'vc-btn.php' );

class WPBakeryShortCode_VC_Basic_Grid extends WPBakeryShortCode_Vc_Pageable {
    public $pagable_type = 'grid';
    public $items = array();
    public static $excluded_ids = array();
    protected $element_template = '';
    protected static $default_max_items = 1000;
    public $post_id = false;
    protected $filter_terms;
    public $attributes_defaults = array(
        'initial_loading_animation' => 'zoomIn',
        'full_width' => '',
        'layout' => '',
        'element_width' => '4',
        'items_per_page' => '5',
        'gap' => '',
        'style' => 'all',
        'show_filter' => '',
        'filter_default_title' => 'all',
        'exclude_filter' => '',
        'filter_style' => '',
        'filter_size' => 'md',
        'filter_align' => '',
        'filter_color' => '',
        'arrows_design' => '',
        'arrows_position' => '',
        'arrows_color' => '',
        'paging_design' => '',
        'paging_color' => '',
        'paging_animation_in' => '',
        'paging_animation_out' => '',
        'loop' => '',
        'autoplay' => '',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'filter_source' => 'category',
        'orderby' => '',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'meta_key' => '',
        'max_items' => '10',
        'offset' => '0',
        'taxonomies' => '',
        'custom_query' => '',
        'data_type' => 'query',
        'include' => '',
        'exclude' => '',
        'item' => 'none',
        'grid_id' => '',
        // disabled, needed for-BC:
        'button_style' => '',
        'button_color' => '',
        'button_size' => '',
        // New button3:
        'btn_title' => '',
        'btn_style' => 'modern',
        'btn_el_id' => '',
        'btn_custom_background' => '#ededed',
        'btn_custom_text' => '#666',
        'btn_outline_custom_color' => '#666',
        'btn_outline_custom_hover_background' => '#666',
        'btn_outline_custom_hover_text' => '#fff',
        'btn_shape' => 'rounded',
        'btn_color' => 'blue',
        'btn_size' => 'md',
        'btn_align' => 'inline',
        'btn_button_block' => '',
        'btn_add_icon' => '',
        'btn_i_align' => 'left',
        'btn_i_type' => 'fontawesome',
        'btn_i_icon_fontawesome' => 'fa fa-adjust',
        'btn_i_icon_openiconic' => 'vc-oi vc-oi-dial',
        'btn_i_icon_typicons' => 'typcn typcn-adjust-brightness',
        'btn_i_icon_entypo' => 'entypo-icon entypo-icon-note',
        'btn_i_icon_linecons' => 'vc_li vc_li-heart',
        'btn_i_icon_pixelicons' => 'vc_pixel_icon vc_pixel_icon-alert',
        'btn_custom_onclick' => '',
        'btn_custom_onclick_code' => '',
        // fix template
        'page_id' => '',
    );
    protected $grid_settings = array();
    protected $grid_id_unique_name = 'vc_gid'; // if you change this also change in hook-vc-grid.php

    function __construct( $settings ) {
        parent::__construct( $settings );
        $this->attributes_defaults['btn_title'] = __( 'Load more', 'js_composer' );
        $this->shortcodeScripts();
    }

    public function shortcodeScripts() {
        parent::shortcodeScripts();

        wp_register_script( 'vc_grid-js-imagesloaded', vc_asset_url( 'lib/bower/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js' ) );
        wp_register_script( 'vc_grid', vc_asset_url( 'js/dist/vc_grid.min.js' ), array(
            'jquery',
            'underscore',
            'vc_pageable_owl-carousel',
            'waypoints',
            //'isotope',
            'vc_grid-js-imagesloaded',
        ), WPB_VC_VERSION, true );
    }

    public function enqueueScripts() {
        parent::enqueueScripts();
        wp_enqueue_script( 'vc_grid-js-imagesloaded' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'vc_grid' );
    }

    public static function addExcludedId( $id ) {
        self::$excluded_ids[] = $id;
    }

    public static function excludedIds() {
        return self::$excluded_ids;
    }

    /**
     * Get shortcode hash by it content and attributes
     *
     * @param $atts
     * @param $content
     *
     * @deprecated 4.4.3
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHash( $atts, $content ) {
        if ( vc_is_page_editable() || is_preview() ) {
            _deprecated_function( 'WPBakeryShortCode_VC_Basic_Grid::getHash', '4.4.3 (will be removed in 4.10)', 'getId resave your grid' );

            /* We are in Frontend editor
             * We need to send RAW shortcode data, so hash is just json_encode of atts and content
             */

            return urlencode( json_encode( array(
                'tag' => $this->shortcode,
                'atts' => $atts,
                'content' => $content,
            ) ) );
        }

        /** Else
         * We are in preview mode (viewing page).
         * So hash is shortcode atts and content hash
         */

        return sha1( serialize( array(
            'tag' => $this->shortcode,
            'atts' => $atts,
            'content' => $content,
        ) ) );

    }

    public function getId( $atts, $content ) {
        if ( vc_is_page_editable() || is_preview() ) {
            /* We are in Frontend editor
             * We need to send RAW shortcode data, so hash is just json_encode of atts and content
             */
            return urlencode( json_encode( array(
                'tag' => $this->shortcode,
                'atts' => $atts,
                'content' => $content,
            ) ) );
        }

        $id_pattern = '/' . $this->grid_id_unique_name . '\:([\w\_-]+)/';

        $id_value = isset( $atts['grid_id'] ) ? $atts['grid_id'] : '';

        preg_match( $id_pattern, $id_value, $id_matches );
        $id_to_save = json_encode( array( 'failed_to_get_id' => esc_attr( $id_value ) ) );

        if ( ! empty( $id_matches ) ) {
            $id_to_save = $id_matches[1];
        }

        return $id_to_save;
    }

    /**
     * Search in post meta vc_post_settings value
     * For shortcode data by hash
     *
     * @param $page_id
     * @param $hash
     *
     * @deprecated 4.4.3
     * @return bool|array
     */
    public function findPostShortcodeByHash( $page_id, $hash ) {
        _deprecated_function( 'WPBakeryShortCode_VC_Basic_Grid::findPostShortcodeByHash', '4.4.3 (will be removed in 5.3)', 'findPostShortcodeById resave your grid to renew' );

        if ( $hash ) {
            if ( $this->currentUserCanManage( $page_id ) && preg_match( '/\"tag\"\:/', urldecode( $hash ) ) ) {
                return json_decode( urldecode( $hash ), true ); // if frontend, no hash exists - just RAW data
            }
            $post_meta = get_post_meta( (int) $page_id, '_vc_post_settings' );
            if ( is_array( $post_meta ) ) {
                foreach ( $post_meta as $meta ) {
                    if ( isset( $meta['vc_grid'] ) && ! empty( $meta['vc_grid']['shortcodes'] ) && isset( $meta['vc_grid']['shortcodes'][ $hash ] ) ) {
                        return $meta['vc_grid']['shortcodes'][ $hash ];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function findPostShortcodeById( $page_id, $grid_id ) {
        if ( $this->currentUserCanManage( $page_id ) && preg_match( '/\"tag\"\:/', urldecode( $grid_id ) ) ) {
            return json_decode( urldecode( $grid_id ), true ); // if frontend, no hash exists - just RAW data
        }
        $post_meta = get_post_meta( (int) $page_id, '_vc_post_settings' );
        if ( is_array( $post_meta ) ) {
            foreach ( $post_meta as $meta ) {
                if ( isset( $meta['vc_grid_id'] ) && ! empty( $meta['vc_grid_id']['shortcodes'] ) && isset( $meta['vc_grid_id']['shortcodes'][ $grid_id ] ) ) {
                    return $meta['vc_grid_id']['shortcodes'][ $grid_id ];
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private function renderItems() {
        $output = $items = '';
        $this->buildGridSettings();
        $atts = $this->atts;
        $settings = $this->grid_settings;
        $filter_terms = $this->filter_terms;
        $is_end = isset( $this->is_end ) && $this->is_end;
        $css_classes = 'vc_grid vc_row' . esc_attr( $atts['gap'] > 0 ? ' vc_grid-gutter-' . (int) $atts['gap'] . 'px' : '' );
        if ( is_array( $this->items ) && ! empty( $this->items ) ) {
            require_once vc_path_dir( 'PARAMS_DIR', 'vc_grid_item/class-vc-grid-item.php' );
            $grid_item = new Vc_Grid_Item();
            $grid_item->setGridAttributes( $atts );
            $grid_item->setIsEnd( $is_end );
            $grid_item->setTemplateById( $atts['item'] );
            $output .= $grid_item->addShortcodesCustomCss();
            ob_start();
            wp_print_styles();
            $output .= ob_get_clean();
            $attributes = array(
                'filter_terms' => $filter_terms,
                'atts' => $atts,
                'grid_item',
                $grid_item,
            );
            $output .= apply_filters( 'vc_basic_grid_template_filter', vc_get_template( 'shortcodes/vc_basic_grid_filter.php', $attributes ), $attributes );
            while ( have_posts() ) {
                the_post();
                $items .= $grid_item->renderItem( get_post() );
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }
        $items = apply_filters( $this->shortcode . '_items_list', $items );
        $output .= $this->renderPagination( $atts['style'], $settings, $items, $css_classes );

        return $output;
    }

    public function setContentLimits() {
        $atts = $this->atts;
        if ( 'ids' === $this->atts['post_type'] ) {
            $this->atts['max_items'] = 0;
            $this->atts['offset'] = 0;
            $this->atts['items_per_page'] = apply_filters( 'vc_basic_grid_max_items', self::$default_max_items );
        } else {
            $this->atts['offset'] = $offset = isset( $atts['offset'] ) ? (int) $atts['offset'] : $this->attributes_defaults['offset'];
            $this->atts['max_items'] = isset( $atts['max_items'] ) ? (int) $atts['max_items'] : (int) $this->attributes_defaults['max_items'];
            $this->atts['items_per_page'] = ! isset( $atts['items_per_page'] ) ? (int) $this->attributes_defaults['items_per_page'] : (int) $atts['items_per_page'];
            if ( $this->atts['max_items'] < 1 ) {
                $this->atts['max_items'] = apply_filters( 'vc_basic_grid_max_items', self::$default_max_items );
            }
        }
        $this->setPagingAll( $this->atts['max_items'] );
    }

    protected function setPagingAll( $max_items ) {
        $atts = $this->atts;
        $this->atts['items_per_page'] = $this->atts['query_items_per_page'] = $max_items > 0 ? $max_items : apply_filters( 'vc_basic_grid_items_per_page_all_max_items', self::$default_max_items );
        $this->atts['query_offset'] = isset( $atts['offset'] ) ? (int) $atts['offset'] : $this->attributes_defaults['offset'];
    }

    public function renderAjax( $vc_request_param ) {
        $this->items = array(); // clear this items array (if used more than once);
        $id = isset( $vc_request_param['shortcode_id'] ) ? $vc_request_param['shortcode_id'] : false;
        if ( ! isset( $vc_request_param['page_id'] ) ) {
            return json_encode( array( 'status' => 'Nothing found' ) );
        }
        if ( $id ) {
            $shortcode = $this->findPostShortcodeById( $vc_request_param['page_id'], $id );
        } else {
            /**
             * @deprecated since 4.4.3 due to invalid logic in hash algorithm
             */
            $hash = isset( $vc_request_param['shortcode_hash'] ) ? $vc_request_param['shortcode_hash'] : false;
            $shortcode = $this->findPostShortcodeByHash( $vc_request_param['page_id'], $hash );
        }
        if ( ! is_array( $shortcode ) ) {
            return json_encode( array( 'status' => 'Nothing found' ) );
        }
        visual_composer()->registerAdminCss();
        visual_composer()->registerAdminJavascript();
        // Set post id
        $this->post_id = (int) $vc_request_param['page_id'];

        $shortcode_atts = $shortcode['atts'];
        $this->shortcode_content = $shortcode['content'];
        $this->buildAtts( $shortcode_atts, $shortcode['content'] );

        $this->buildItems();

        return $this->renderItems();
    }

    public function postID() {
        if ( false == $this->post_id ) {
            $this->post_id = get_the_ID();
        }

        return $this->post_id;
    }

    public function buildAtts( $atts, $content ) {
        $arr_keys = array_keys( $atts );
        for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $atts ); $i ++ ) {
            $atts[ $arr_keys[ $i ] ] = html_entity_decode( $atts[ $arr_keys[ $i ] ], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8' );
        }
        if ( isset( $atts['grid_id'] ) && ! empty( $atts['grid_id'] ) ) {
            $id_to_save = $this->getId( $atts, $content );
        } else {
            $hash = $this->getHash( $atts, $content );
        }

        $atts = $this->convertButton2ToButton3( $atts );
        $atts = shortcode_atts( $this->attributes_defaults, vc_map_get_attributes( $this->getShortcode(), $atts ) );
        $this->atts = $atts;
        if ( isset( $id_to_save ) ) {
            $this->atts['shortcode_id'] = $id_to_save;
        } else if ( isset( $hash ) ) {
            $this->atts['shortcode_hash'] = $hash;
        }
        $this->atts['page_id'] = $this->postID();

        $this->element_template = $content;
        // @since 4.4.3
        if ( 'custom' === $this->attr( 'post_type' ) ) {
            $this->atts['style'] = 'all';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Getter attribute.
     *
     * @param $key
     *
     * @return mixed|null
     */
    public function attr( $key ) {
        return isset( $this->atts[ $key ] ) ? $this->atts[ $key ] : null;
    }

    public function buildGridSettings() {
        $this->grid_settings = array(
            'page_id' => $this->atts['page_id'],
            // used in basic grid for initialization
            'style' => $this->atts['style'],
            'action' => 'vc_get_vc_grid_data',
        );
        // used in ajax request for items
        if ( isset( $this->atts['shortcode_id'] ) && ! empty( $this->atts['shortcode_id'] ) ) {
            $this->grid_settings['shortcode_id'] = $this->atts['shortcode_id'];
        } elseif ( isset( $this->atts['shortcode_hash'] ) && ! empty( $this->atts['shortcode_hash'] ) ) {
            // @deprecated since 4.4.3
            $this->grid_settings['shortcode_hash'] = $this->atts['shortcode_hash'];
        }
        if ( 'load-more' === $this->atts['style'] ) {
            $this->grid_settings = array_merge( $this->grid_settings, array(
                // used in dispaly style load more button, lazy, pagination
                'items_per_page' => $this->atts['items_per_page'],
                'btn_data' => vc_map_integrate_parse_atts( $this->shortcode, 'vc_btn', $this->atts, 'btn' . '_' ),
            ) );
        } elseif ( 'lazy' === $this->atts['style'] ) {
            $this->grid_settings = array_merge( $this->grid_settings, array(
                'items_per_page' => $this->atts['items_per_page'],
            ) );
        } elseif ( 'pagination' === $this->atts['style'] ) {
            $this->grid_settings = array_merge( $this->grid_settings, array(
                'items_per_page' => $this->atts['items_per_page'],
                // used in pagination style
                'auto_play' => $this->atts['autoplay'] > 0 ? true : false,
                'gap' => (int) $this->atts['gap'],
                // not used yet, but can be used in isotope..
                'speed' => (int) $this->atts['autoplay'] * 1000,
                'loop' => $this->atts['loop'],
                'animation_in' => $this->atts['paging_animation_in'],
                'animation_out' => $this->atts['paging_animation_out'],
                'arrows_design' => $this->atts['arrows_design'],
                'arrows_color' => $this->atts['arrows_color'],
                'arrows_position' => $this->atts['arrows_position'],
                'paging_design' => $this->atts['paging_design'],
                'paging_color' => $this->atts['paging_color'],
            ) );
        }
        $this->grid_settings['tag'] = $this->shortcode;
    }

    // TODO: setter & getter to attributes
    public function buildQuery( $atts ) {
        // Set include & exclude
        if ( 'ids' !== $atts['post_type'] && ! empty( $atts['exclude'] ) ) {
            $atts['exclude'] .= ',' . implode( ',', $this->excludedIds() );
        } else {
            $atts['exclude'] = implode( ',', $this->excludedIds() );
        }
        if ( 'ids' !== $atts['post_type'] ) {
            $settings = array(
                'posts_per_page' => $atts['query_items_per_page'],
                'offset' => $atts['query_offset'],
                'orderby' => $atts['orderby'],
                'order' => $atts['order'],
                'meta_key' => in_array( $atts['orderby'], array(
                    'meta_value',
                    'meta_value_num',
                ) ) ? $atts['meta_key'] : '',
                'post_type' => $atts['post_type'],
                'exclude' => $atts['exclude'],
            );
            if ( ! empty( $atts['taxonomies'] ) ) {
                $vc_taxonomies_types = get_taxonomies( array( 'public' => true ) );
                $terms = get_terms( array_keys( $vc_taxonomies_types ), array(
                    'hide_empty' => false,
                    'include' => $atts['taxonomies'],
                ) );
                $settings['tax_query'] = array();
                $tax_queries = array(); // List of taxnonimes
                foreach ( $terms as $t ) {
                    if ( ! isset( $tax_queries[ $t->taxonomy ] ) ) {
                        $tax_queries[ $t->taxonomy ] = array(
                            'taxonomy' => $t->taxonomy,
                            'field' => 'id',
                            'terms' => array( $t->term_id ),
                            'relation' => 'IN',
                        );
                    } else {
                        $tax_queries[ $t->taxonomy ]['terms'][] = $t->term_id;
                    }
                }
                $settings['tax_query'] = array_values( $tax_queries );
                $settings['tax_query']['relation'] = 'OR';
            }
        } else {
            if ( empty( $atts['include'] ) ) {
                $atts['include'] = - 1;
            } elseif ( ! empty( $atts['exclude'] ) ) {
                $include = array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $atts['include'] ) );
                $exclude = array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $atts['exclude'] ) );
                $diff = array_diff( $include, $exclude );
                $atts['include'] = implode( ', ', $diff );
            }
            $settings = array(
                'include' => $atts['include'],
                'posts_per_page' => $atts['query_items_per_page'],
                'offset' => $atts['query_offset'],
                'post_type' => 'any',
                'orderby' => 'post__in',
            );
            $this->atts['items_per_page'] = - 1;
        }

        return $settings;
    }

    public function buildItems() {
        $this->filter_terms = $this->items = array();

        $this->setContentLimits();

        $this->addExcludedId( $this->postID() );
        if ( 'custom' === $this->atts['post_type'] && ! empty( $this->atts['custom_query'] ) ) {
            $query = html_entity_decode( vc_value_from_safe( $this->atts['custom_query'] ), ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8' );
            $post_data = query_posts( $query );
            $this->atts['items_per_page'] = - 1;
        } elseif ( false !== $this->atts['query_items_per_page'] ) {
            $settings = $this->filterQuerySettings( $this->buildQuery( $this->atts ) );
            $post_data = query_posts( $settings );
        } else {
            return;
        }
        if ( $this->atts['items_per_page'] > 0 && count( $post_data ) > $this->atts['items_per_page'] ) {
            $post_data = array_slice( $post_data, 0, $this->atts['items_per_page'] );
        }
        foreach ( $post_data as $post ) {
            $post->filter_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $this->atts['filter_source'], array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
            $this->filter_terms = wp_parse_args( $this->filter_terms, $post->filter_terms );
            $this->items[] = $post;
        }
    }

    public function filterQuerySettings( $args ) {
        $defaults = array(
            'numberposts' => 5,
            'offset' => 0,
            'category' => 0,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'include' => array(),
            'exclude' => array(),
            'meta_key' => '',
            'meta_value' => '',
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'suppress_filters' => apply_filters( 'vc_basic_grid_filter_query_suppress_filters', true ),
            'public' => true,
        );

        $r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
        if ( empty( $r['post_status'] ) ) {
            $r['post_status'] = ( 'attachment' === $r['post_type'] ) ? 'inherit' : 'publish';
        }
        if ( ! empty( $r['numberposts'] ) && empty( $r['posts_per_page'] ) ) {
            $r['posts_per_page'] = $r['numberposts'];
        }
        if ( ! empty( $r['category'] ) ) {
            $r['cat'] = $r['category'];
        }
        if ( ! empty( $r['include'] ) ) {
            $incposts = wp_parse_id_list( $r['include'] );
            $r['posts_per_page'] = count( $incposts );  // only the number of posts included
            $r['post__in'] = $incposts;
        } elseif ( ! empty( $r['exclude'] ) ) {
            $r['post__not_in'] = wp_parse_id_list( $r['exclude'] );
        }

        $r['ignore_sticky_posts'] = true;
        $r['no_found_rows'] = true;

        return $r;
    }

    public static function convertButton2ToButton3( $atts ) {
        if ( isset( $atts['button_style'] ) || isset( $atts['button_size'] ) || isset( $atts['button_color'] ) ) {
            // we use old button 2 attributes:
            $style = isset( $atts['button_style'] ) ? $atts['button_style'] : 'rounded';
            $size = isset( $atts['button_size'] ) ? $atts['button_size'] : 'md';
            $color = isset( $atts['button_color'] ) ? $atts['button_color'] : 'blue';
            $oldData = array(
                'style' => $style,
                'size' => $size,
                'color' => str_replace( '_', '-', $color ),
            );
            // remove attributes on save
            $atts['button_style'] = '';
            $atts['button_size'] = '';
            $atts['button_color'] = '';
            $newData = WPBakeryShortCode_VC_Btn::convertAttributesToButton3( $oldData );
            foreach ( $newData as $key => $value ) {
                $atts[ 'btn_' . $key ] = $value;
            }
        }

        return $atts;
    }
}
```

By removing hyphen the warning disappears but the article grid not display

Comment: by using your both propositions, the warning disappears but the grid article does not display

Comment: Moreover, the undescore is already included in `\w`, your regex is equivalent to `:([\w-]+)`

Comment: always the grid article does not display

Comment: Show us the content of each values you are using. It is impossible to say what is wrong without input strings.

Comment: i used  '\:([\w\-_]+)/';   and '\:([\w\_-]+)/';

Comment: What is the content of `$this->grid_id_unique_name` and `$id_value`?

Comment: protected $grid_id_unique_name = 'vc_gid';    and   $id_value = isset( $atts['grid_id'] ) ? $atts['grid_id'] : '';

Comment: What is the **content** of `$id_value`? I don't ask how is it fill, this is already said in the code.

Comment: I posted the entire code on the question

Comment: Can you add the outcome of `var_dump($id_pattern);` to the question?

Comment: Please post only the relevant lines (as you did when you created the question) and add the value of `$id_pattern` that produces the error. As it is now, the question is difficult to read and understand; there is a lot of code that doesn't help.

Comment: @thef this question is not minimal (it is a file dump), it needs debugging details, and is unclear.  If you agree, please vote to close.

Comment: @axiac this question is not minimal (it is a file dump), it needs debugging details, and is unclear.  If you agree, please vote to close.

Comment: @toto this question is not minimal (it is a file dump), it needs debugging details, and is unclear.  If you agree, please vote to close.

Answer (score 3):

just place this code `([\w-]+)` instead of `([\w\_-]+)`

it will work.

Comment: didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$id_pattern = '/' . $this->grid_id_unique_name . '\:([\w\_-]+)/';
preg_match( $id_pattern, $id_value, $id_matches );
```

Apart from the issue you mentioned (or maybe the cause of the issue you mentioned), there is an issue in the way you generate `$id_pattern`.

It is used as the first argument of [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match) that expects it to be a string containing a valid regular . But, because its value is generated and `$this->grid_id_unique_name` may contain anything, including [characters that have special meaning in `regex`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php), `$id_pattern` may end up containing a string that is not a valid `regex`.

When you build a `regex` using dynamic values (user input, values from persistence etc) you need to use [`preg_quote()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to encode the special `regex` characters properly.
The code should be:

```
$id_pattern = '/' . preg_quote($this->grid_id_unique_name, '/') . '\:([\w\_-]+)/';
```

There are other small issues (that does not cause errors) in the fixed part of the `regex`.

The underscore (`_`) is not a special character, there is no need to escape it. Even more the underscore is already included in `\w` (the class [word characters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) - it contains the digits, the letters and the underscore). This renders `_` (escaped or not) completely useless.

Other than that, `:` is a special character in `regex` only in [subpatterns](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php). It does not have any special meaning in this combination. You can safely leave it unescaped.

In the end, the correct generation of `$id_pattern` is:

```
$id_pattern = '/' . preg_quote($this->grid_id_unique_name, '/') . ':([\w-]+)/';
```